# IPhone HTTP Post Text Data and be saved as a text file

Tags: iphone, http

```
NSMutableURLRequest* post = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:   @"http://test.com/upload.php"]];

  [post setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];


  NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------     3587343183674357"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[post addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"textfile\"; filename=\"test.txt\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/multipart/form-data \r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


 NSString* str= @"teststring";
NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[body appendData:data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[post setHTTPBody:body];
```

After the text file is sent, I check my server, the teststring is sent and attached to be part of parameter. No, actually I want it to be in a file named test.txt and be in the directory.  So how can I send that the data in and be in a directory as test.txt file?  I do not want it as just part of the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to write the data to your Documents Directory?
Then use this code...

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[data writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.txt", documentsDirectory] atomically:YES];
```

Comment: No, what you shows is writing in Iphone.  What I trying to do is sending data from Iphone to http Server through Http post operation.    test.txt should ultimately go to the computer.